# import android.support.wearable cannot be resolved

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to develop a simple Android Wear app but I am facing problem:

> import android.support.wearable cannot be resolved

[image]

Comment: Did my answer below get your project building in Eclipse?

Answer (score 11):

The best way to get started with Android Wear is to use the latest Android Studio 0.8.1 or later, and it makes adding the support libraries to your code a lot easier. But it is possible to still use Eclipse, and I'll explain how to do it ...

Since the SDK was just released for Android Wear, you need to firstly make sure you follow these instructions to get everything up to date: http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html

Here are the steps you need to do to fix your problem:

1. Start SDK Manager.
2. Update the Android SDK Tools and Platform-tools to versions 23 and 20 respectively.
3. Click Tools > Manage Add-on Sites > User Defined Sites.
4. Click New, enter https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-play-services-5.xml into the text field, and click OK.
5. Click Close. You should now see lots of packages that need to be downloaded. You need to download "SDK Platform" under "Android 4.4W (API 20)
6. The most important part is to download the "Google Repository" package under "Extras".
7. Step 6 will produce a directory called $SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.0.0 and in there will be a wearable-1.0.0.aar file
8. Unzip the wearable-1.0.0.aar file, and it will produce a classes.jar file
9. If you unzip -v classes.jar you will see that it contains android/support/wearable/view/WatchViewStuff.class, which is what you were looking for!
10. Copy this classes.jar file to your project's libs directory, rename it to something like wearable-classes.jar
11. Right click on the libs directory in Eclipse, which will refresh your project and you should see wearable-classes.jar
12. Clean and rebuild your project.

These steps might seem complicated in having to deal with the .aar file ... It is a lot easier when working with Android Studio, since you can just add a gradle rule that does all these steps for you automatically:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.+"
}
```

Comment: It works thanks. All these folder names are very confusing... why can't things be simple?

Comment: That is not a complete answer though... you also need all the resources and assets from that aar file.

Comment: I tried it out when I wrote the instructions. You don't need to copy over the resources unless you reference them in your app.

Comment: Obviously. I'm just simulating how to add the aar to your project using Eclipse.

Comment: Okay above instructions helped me but i have another issue "WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I didn't need to add the user-defined site.  Google Repository was already in my list, and once I installed it gradle was able to finish building.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio you still need to do steps 1 to 6 above. Then if you have the compile time dependency shown above it should build without having to manually extract the jar file in steps 7 to 12.

Comment: @WaynePiekarski Could you please help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855788/android-wear-lib-file-jar-instead-of-aar-extension

Answer (score 3):

in the spirit of @Wayne Piekarski answer, I've [created a repository](https://bitbucket.org/nu-art-public/android-google-libs) that stores the project as you will need it for developing in Eclipse, clone it -> add it as an Android Library -> DONE!

Lets keep it simple :)

==== UPDATE ====

And if you still encounter the WearableActivity... simply replace it with another Activity of you choice.

Comment: I have eclipse and i have followed this link :
http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development
but still the import "WatchViewStub"  and "DismissOverlayView" cannot be resolved . and ElizaChat sample wearable app is working for me , so why WatchViewStub sample is not working ? what's missing ?

Comment: I did but still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Create a wearable module with Android Studio 4.0 and ended-up with the exact same issue! And it's 2020, 6 years later LOL.

Followed this guide to add the missing bits and pieces:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating

Basically my project builde.gradle didn't have those:

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

And this is module's gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.0'
```

Once added, every checked properly.

PS: the maven is not even needed. Only missing implementation which clearly shows the wizard fails to create a valid module.

Comment: One year later and still not fixed. Notice how this is the support library, you need to keep compileOnly on the other one with the same versionnumber as well. WearableActivity is now deprecated too, which makes this even worse.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android SDK Manager, go to tools > manage add-on sites > user defined sites > new:
 https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-play-services-5.xml

Make sure you have the following (this is what I have)

1) Android SDK Tools v 23 (23.0.1 just came out)

2) Android SDK Platform-tools v 20

3) Android SDK Build-tools v 20

4) Android 4.4W (API 20)

5) Android Support Repository

6) Android Support Library

7) Everything else up to date

Resources:
http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: I don't think this will help solve the question since android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub is present in the wearable-1.0.0.aar file that comes from the Google Repository. Also, you need to extract out the classes.jar from the aar file. See my answer below, which is needed for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions detailed at the link below were very helpful for my Eclipse setup.

https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d

Answer (score 0):

For gradle try

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### Maven?

AndroidSDK uses their very own repository. After download copy all from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\
```

To your repository. So this can be resolved:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.wearable</groupId>
        <artifactId>wearable</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- or whatever -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And you will get your

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.148 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-23T09:10:12+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/15381M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```